# Show that a set of linear transformations is a linear subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ and $W$ be linear spaces over $k$ and $V_1 \subset V$ and $W_1 \subset W$ be linear subspaces of $V$ and $W$, respectively. Show that the set of linear transformations

$$\{ \phi \in L(V,W): \ \alpha \in V_1 \implies \phi(\alpha) \in W_1 \}$$

is a linear subspace of $L(V,W)$.

I go about this in the following way. We need to show $(\phi_1 + \phi_2) \in L(V,W)$ and $c \phi \in L(V,W)$.

For $\alpha \in V_1$, we have
$$(\phi_1 + \phi_2)(\alpha) = \phi_1(\alpha) + \phi_2(\alpha)$$
From $\alpha \in V_1 \implies \phi(\alpha) \in W_1$,we know $\phi_1(\alpha) \in W_1$ and $\phi_2(\alpha) \in W_1$. The fact that $W_1$ is a linear subspace gives us
$$(\phi_1 + \phi_2)(\alpha) = \phi_1(\alpha) + \phi_2(\alpha) \in W_1$$
So
$$(\phi_1 + \phi_2) \in L(V,W)$$
Repeating this and using the fact that $(c \phi)(\alpha) = c\phi(\alpha)$ will give us
$$c \phi \in L(V,W)$$
Is this reasoning correct? In particular, I haven't used the fact that $V_1$ is a linear subspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct.  Indeed, you did not need to use the fact that $V_1$ was a subspace.  In fact, the same reasoning can be applied to the space of functions of the form $f:X\to W$ where $X$ is *any* kind of space and $W$ is a vector space.